# Is there a way to set global/default system settings (specifically GUI Scaling)

Tags: unity, 14.04, system-settings, dpi

I added Ubuntu 14.04 to my system (MacBookPro11,3) which has a HiDPI screen. In system settings, I was able to set the GUI scaling to 2.0 for my own account, and I'm happy about that. However, the login screen uses the default 1.0 scaling, which makes it difficult to log in to my account. In addition, the guest account uses the 1.0 scaling, but that's less of an issue. Is there a configuration somewhere that I can use to adjust the default settings for the system? I would personally also like to turn off tap-to-click globally, but that's something I can deal with.

Comment: How did you setup you user scaling, using dconf/gsettings?

Comment: You can set the scale factor (defaults to 1.0) per user in System Settings > Display.